# VLC Lua scripting https request

Tags: https, lua, vlc

I'm writing a small vlc extension for nba league pass, actually i rewrite kodi addon for vlc, and i'm stuck at very beginning with LogIn function, i write working lua script in ZeroBrain Studio

```
http = require("socket.http")
json = require("dkjson")
ltn12 = require("ltn12")
https = require("ssl/https")

data = "username=user&password=pass"

res, code, response_headers, status = https.request {
    response_body = {} , 
    method = "POST",
    headers= {
      ["Content-Type"]="application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      ["Content-Length"] = data:len()
      },
    url = 'https://watch.nba.com/nba/secure/login?',
    source = ltn12.source.string(data),
    sink = ltn12.sink.table(response_body)  
}

print (response_headers["set-cookie"])
```

Problem is that it uses "https". I've tried do [this](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=109033#p370635) but get  error

```
Error while running script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\extensions\nba_league_pass.lua, function (null)(): error loading module 'socket.core' from file '.\socket\core.dll': dynamic libraries not enabled; check your Lua installation
```

So, my question is how to make https request in vlc?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> error loading module 'socket.core' from file '.\socket\core.dll': dynamic libraries not enabled; check your Lua installation

"dynamic libraries not enabled" usually indicates that your Lua interpreter is compiled without `LUA_DL_DLL` compilation flag (on Windows); specifying this compilation flag enables loading of dynamic libraries. (The Lua interpreter would be the one packaged with or embedded into VLC if that's what you are running.)

Comment: You are right, this is what i found in old vlc git https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/master/contrib/src/lua/no-dylibs.patch but new versions use the same code(patch), so now i need to compile vlc with that flag, it's never easy with open source. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Dmitriy, you may want to accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Still can't compile it, it tells that can't find Lua, but i installed Lua5.2 and dev-lua, i will accept it after compile. I've tried earlier versions of VLC, 2.0.9 is the last without that patch and i get 'dynamic libraries not enabled' error too

Comment: You need to look at the settings it's compiled with or find a way to compile with the settings you need. You won't be able to make dynamic libraries to work without that support compiled in.

Comment: I understand, but i cant even compile vlc from the sources, don't know what is whrong. So I can't tell you is your answer help me or not. I think it is right way but can't check.

Comment: So i give up, but i accept your answer because you were tried to help